# Why Angular CLI@7.3.9 does not update angular.json with new test target when creating a library component

Tags: angular-cli

The expected behavior when creating a new component using `angular-cli` is that `angular.json.projects` is updated with an entry describing the newly created component. The observed behavior is that `angular-cli` does not do so.

I found this out after running `ng test newComponent` and receiving the message `Project 'inline' does not support the 'test' target.`

The `ng test newComponent` worked after I updated `angular.json.projects` to describe the newly created component.

I'm migrating an Angular 2 component library to the new Angular 7 Workspace model. I'm building it from scratch using Todd Palmer's [The Angular Library Series - Creating a Library with Angular CLI](https://blog.angularindepth.com/creating-a-library-in-angular-6-87799552e7e5) recipe.

Although the [recipe](https://blog.angularindepth.com/creating-a-library-in-angular-6-87799552e7e5) does not recommend testing a newly created component, I did and observed the failure herein described.

**Steps to reproduce**

- using angular-cli@7.3.9 create a library workspace

```
ng new workspace --create-application=false
```

- Create a library

```
ng generate library library --prefix=abc
```

- Create a testing application, I call it a living style guide

```
ng generate application living-style-guide
```

- Create a new library component

```
ng generate component newComponent —project=library
```

- Validate the component creation

```
ng test newComponent —project=library
```

**Observed Behavior**
The last command fails with the following message

```
Project 'newComponent' does not support the 'test' target.
Error: Project 'newComponent' does not support the 'test' target.
    at TestCommand.initialize (./node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:53:19)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:757:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

**Expected Behavior**
angular-cli updates angular.json projects object with a description of newly created library components and their unit tests pass.

Answer (score 0):

Discussed this with Alan Agius, from angular-cli. Alan explained to me that `ng test <target>` is designed to work only for `projects`, not library components; he suggested I follow their issue #[3603](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3603).

I closed my last email to Alan by reminding him that a developer who has a library with a lot of components, is developing a new component, and wishes to target the component in development for testing, should be able to do it with a simple `ng` command.